# How do I use HTML5 intellisense in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to write HTML5 tags in visual studio 2010 but when I attempted to write for example the `<video></video>` tags it underline in green and hover information: *Validation(XHTML 1.0 Transitional) Element video is not supported*. I have installed SP1 on my PC already but the tags are not coming up. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this add-in which seems to cover most of it.  I still get the ocassional XHTML1.0 reference but what can you say..

[HTML5 Intellisense for VS 2010 and 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link below
[HTML5 Support In Visual Studio 2010](http://www.raihaniqbal.net/blog/2010/08/html5-support-in-visual-studio-2010/)

1.Download this archive and extract the contents to your desktop.

2.Copy/Move html_5.xsd to D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html. The path may vary depending on where you installed VS 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010.

3.From the extracted contents, run the appropriate registry file. In my case, it was VS-2010-x64.reg

4.Now fire up Visual Studio 2010 (or VWD) and navigate to Tools > Options > Text Editor HTML > Validation. On the right panel, select HTML 5 as the Target.